# How to connect Onion Omega relay board to AC110V Electric Solenoid Valve

Tags: relay, home-automation, solenoid-valve

I am a electronics newbie who wants to connect a Onion Omega to a AC110 V Electric Solenoid Valve (such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007N0J98E) for example) with their [Relay extension board](https://store.onion.io/collections/onion-omega-expansions/products/relay-expansion). Do I need any capacitors/transistor/etc?

Comment: Please add some specifics to this question. A schematic of what portion of your design you've come up with so far would be helpful. Also, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour has many helpful guidelines for how to write 'better questions.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relay board says it will handle 60W (one or both- it's not really clear); the solenoid valve says it takes 18W.

As such it appears it should work.

It's a good idea to put a MOV (Varistor) or **bidirectional** TVS across the solenoid coil rated for the AC voltage used (so at least 200V peak DC voltage). For example, a P6KE250CA, because the high inductance of a solenoid valve coil will cause a lot of contact sparking and electrical noise.

Generally relays rated at only 2A are not really intended to switch that kind of load and have a life that is very many operations, but there's no real information what the actual relay rating is, only the board (so the relay may be derated).

Comment: Thanks! I know this is unrelated to my earlier question but any recommendation on reading material where I could read up on this?

Comment: Look at the application information from solenoid valve manufacturers in particular. For example, [this](http://www.automationdirect.com/static/specs/solenoidvalvecablesconn.pdf) one.